# Is [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] a serial queue?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

The following method uploads some images to a remote server. I want them to be upload independent of each other (in parallel).

```
- (void)startUploadProcess {
    for (int i = 0; i < [imageNames count]; i++) {
        NSBlockOperation *blockOp = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            [GlobalsFuncs uploadImageToServer:[[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[imagePaths objectAtIndex:i]]  forSessionID:[[family SessionID] stringValue]  withFilename:[imageNames objectAtIndex:i]];
        }];

        blockOp.completionBlock = ^{
            [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
                [self afterUploadCompletion:i];
            }];
        };
        [bgQueue addOperation:blockOp];
    }
}

- (void)afterUploadCompletion:(NSInteger)pageNumber {
    NSLog(@"%ld for sessionID : %@", (long)pageNumber, family.SessionID);
    imagesUploaded++;
    [progressIndicator incrementBy:progressDelta];
}
```

As you can see from the code above, I'm adding a call to the `afterUploadCompletion` method for each image. In that method, I'm incrementing an integer that is a class instance variable. My question is if my code will ever cause a race condition? Basically, what I'm asking is if everything in the `mainQueue` is executed serially? 
Also, how can I make the `NSOperationQueue *bgQueue` a parallel queue? I want blocks added to this queue to NOT wait for previous operations to complete.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Why don't u just print number of concurrent ops that it supports in debugger. It would save good 10 minutes of typing this question. Besides there is a handy documentation available online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSOperationQueue/mainQueue) `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` performs operation in serial manner:-

**The `[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]` returned queue executes one operation at a time on the app’s main thread. The execution of operations on the main thread is interleaved with the other tasks that must execute on the main thread, such as the servicing of events and the updating of an app’s user interface. The queue executes those operations in the run loop common modes, as represented by the NSRunLoopCommonModes constant.**

Now if you want to execute the operation in concurrent or parallel manner. Refer the below sample:-

```
NSOperationQueue * queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
NSOperation * nwOperation = [[yourOper alloc] init];
[queue addOperation:nwOperation];
```

**So if you add multiple operations to a queue, they all execute in parallel on background threads, allowing your main thread to deal with the user interface. The queue will intelligently schedule the number of parallel operations based on the number of CPU cores your users have, thus effectively taking advantage of your users’ hardware.**

*EDIT*:-

For more information about concurrent operations refer this [Dave Dribin's blog.](http://www.dribin.org/dave/blog/archives/2009/05/05/concurrent_operations/)

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted a queue created with [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] to be serial as well? Would setting its 'maxConcurrentOperationCount' to 1 be a good way to do that?

Comment: As per David's blog, you can use the queue to limit the number of parallel downloads using setMaxConcurrentOperationCount.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the main queue is always serial. Any queue created with `[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]` will be concurrent, meaning operations passed to it will run in parallel.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I wanted a queue created with [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] to be serial as well? Would setting its 'maxConcurrentOperationCount' to 1 be a good way to do that?

Comment: Yes. Keep in mind that you should use the same priority among all of your operations in order to prevent priority inversions among concurrent queues.